# "The request body is either invalid or incomplete."

Tags: date, einstein-analytics, dashboard, filters, custom-reports

I'm using the analytics studio to build a dashboard right now. I put 2 reports about campaign influence, that I created via *"Reports"*, one for customers and one for prospects. I want to put a filter on the dashboard so it can filter out both reports.

The problem is, even if I connect the data sources (In this case, the campaign start date from the campaign (salesforce object) and the campaign start date from campaign influence) when I use the filter, it gives me an error:

***Can't display this widget.** **More Details***

And when I click on more details,

***The request body is either invalid or incomplete.***

What's the reason? And what is the fix for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.